# I want my OS on a separate hard drive than the rest of the data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and I just finished building a new computer. It has an 120 GB hard drive, where I want the (soon to be) 2 OSes on it (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Windows 10).

I can't figure out how to get the computer with Ubuntu on it and send the rest of the data to my 4 TB hard drive.

Comment: the Hard drive with the OS has 2 Filesystem Partitions on it, im not sure about mounting a Partition same as the /etc/fatab

Comment: Look up how to create a data partition on the 4TB drive...unless, of course, the 4TB drive is already partitioned the way you want it. Then look up how to use the 'mount' command in Ubuntu so the OS can read/write the data partition.

Comment: You can create or move your home directory to a "/home" partition, It can be located on your 4TB data drive. If you move it, (I use rsync), let /etc/fstab know where it is. If installing and building a new filesystem, you can select a partition on the 4TB for /home using something else. You can also move your Windows User data to a second hard drive, see: https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-change-the-location-of-user-folders-in-windows-10/